# Pyspark: How do I get today's score and 30 day avg score in a single row

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I have use-case where I want to get the rank for today as well as 30 day average as a column. The data has 30 day data for a particular ID and type. The data looks like: -

```
  Id     Type        checkInDate      avgrank
   1     ALONE       2019-04-24      1.333333
   1     ALONE       2019-03-31      34.057471
   2     ALONE       2019-04-17      1.660842
   1     TOGETHER    2019-04-13      19.500000
   1     TOGETHER    2019-04-08      5.481203
   2     ALONE       2019-03-29      122.449156
   3     ALONE       2019-04-07      3.375000
   1     TOGETHER    2019-04-01      49.179719
   5     TOGETHER    2019-04-17      1.391753
   2     ALONE       2019-04-22      3.916667
   1     ALONE       2019-04-15      2.459151
```

As my result I want to have output like

```
  Id     Type        TodayAvg        30DayAvg
   1     ALONE       30.0            9.333333
   1     TOGETHER    1.0             34.057471
   2     ALONE       7.8             99.660842
   2     TOGETHER    3               19.500000
```

.
.

The way I think I can achieve it is having 2 dataframes, one doing a filter on today's date and the 2nd dataframe doing an average over 30 days and then joining the today dataframes on ID and Type

```
rank = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database="testing", table_name="rank", transformation_ctx="rank")

filtert_rank = Filter.apply(frame=rank, f=lambda x: (x["checkInDate"] == curr_dt))

rank_avg = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database="testing", table_name="rank", transformation_ctx="rank_avg")

rank_avg_f = rank_avg.groupBy("id", "type").agg(F.mean("avgrank"))

rank_join = filtert_rank.join(rank_avg, ["id", "type"], how='inner')
```

Is there a simpler way to do it i.e. without reading the dataframe twice?

Comment: I don't know too much about the dataset you're using there, but please exercise caution when doing a mean of a mean (i.e. F.mean("avgrank") ), it might not be giving you exactly what you want, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_mean

Comment: The calculations do not add up to the Output. Eg. for id = 1 and type= Alone, the average calculates to 12.62
Also for reference what is the value of the curr_dt?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the dynamic frame to a apache spark data frame and perform regular sql.

Check the documentation for toDF() and sparksql.